# C++ extending lifetime of &&

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, temporary

In the following example:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a1df22bb73f6030

```
struct D{
    int i;    
    auto test2(int&& j){
        return [&](){       // captured by reference!
            cout << i*(j);
        };
    }    
};

int main()
{
    D d{10};
    {
      auto fn = d.test2(10);
      fn();                     // 1. wrong result here

      d.test2(10)();            // 2. but ok here
    }
}
```

Why does `d.test2(10)();` work?

Should it really work, or thats just my undefined behavior equals correct result?

**P.S.** After reading [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) I see only one explanation: in (2) temporary lifetime prolongs till the end of the expression, and call happens in the same expression with && crteation; while (1) actually consists from 2 expressions:

> a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists
>   until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if
>   the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression,
>   it becomes a dangling reference.

Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, the answer you found and put in your question is the correct answer.

Comment: @hvd - Are you sure? I actually can't find defeintion of "expression".

Comment: Yes, quite sure. "Expression" is a production in the grammar. "Full-expression" is defined in [intro.execution]p10, and basically means "expression that is not a subexpression", meaning the only full-expression in the `d.test2(10)();` statement is `d.test2(10)()`.

Comment: @hwd - So... may "Expression" be recognized by ";" or sequence points? I mean can I do something with line like `d.test2(10)();` to accidently break expression in a two (and therefore get dangling reference)?

Comment: @AnT Yes - you're right, with `const int&` I getting the same behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary object lasts until the end of the *line* (well, full expression) where it is created, unless the lifetime is extended.

Your code does not extend the lifetimes of any temporaries.  Lifetime extension through binding to references does not "commute", only the first binding extends lifetime.

So the furst case is UB as you have a dangling reference.  The referred to temporary goes away st the end of the line: on the next line uou follow the reference, and chaos hapens.

In the second case, your reference does not extend the lifetime of the temporary, but the temporary lasts longer than the reference that binds to it does!  They both die at the end of the line, in reverse order of construction.

So the call works.

Comment: by *line* you mean *full-expression*  - it's possible to have multiple statements on one line of course

Comment: @M.M yes, someone could string a bunch of `;` delimited full expressions together.  :)  And a full expression could span more than one line.

Comment: @Yakk: Do you know a reference in the standard for why "Lifetime extension through binding to references does not 'commute'"? Or maybe better, a heuristic explanation to help remember and explain why it is this way?

Comment: @chris references in certain contexts extend lifetime of temporary to the reference.  There is no clause that causes one reference bound to another to extend it further.  There is an exception for temporaries bound to references in constructors, but that shortens lifetime not extends it further.  Not sure how to cite an absence!  Maybe there is a note.  The english version of the rule is: temporaries bound directly to references have their lifetime extended to the reference lifetime, except if in a ctor initilaizer list.  Otherwise, temporaries go away at the `;` (roughly)

Answer (score -1):

> Should it really work, or thats just my undefined behavior equals correct result?

Seems like it. In the example you linked, you have these warnings:

```
warning: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Uninitialized objects have indetermine values, and trying to access those values results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Only some versions of gcc throw it. clang generate no warnings at all.

Comment: Sorry, but you're misreading the warnings. If you comment out the calls that the OP already noted as not working, you'll find that GCC doesn't give any warnings, and it's right not to.